# How can I get the primary key of the last insered quote?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have 2 views: display_quote and quote_create.

```py
def display_quote(request, pk):
    items_quote = Quote.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    items_quote_line = LineQuote.objects.all().filter(num_quote_id=pk)

    form = QuoteLineForm(request.POST or None)
       if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    total = 0
    for item in items_quote_line:
        total = total + item.get_price()

    context = {'items_quote': items_quote,
               'items_quote_line': items_quote_line,
               'form': form,
               'total':total
              }

    return render(request, 'quote/quote_display.html', context)


def quote_create(request):
    form = QuoteForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'quote/quote_create.html', {'form': form})
```

After creating a quote, I want to redirect to "display_quote" (the quote creted).
Error obtained:
The view quote.views.quote_create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
def quote_create(request):
    form = QuoteForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'quote/quote_create.html', {'form': form})
     return render(request, "...", {})
```

return something by default. Else conditions are not handled here...